# how to implement a generic interface to child class in java

Tags: java, arraylist

What if interface class has generic extends, how to implement that interface to other class?

I am confused to how to implement interface with generic and inheritance

```
interface Obj < T extends Number >
{
   ArrayList< T > getResult();
}

class Value
{
   ArrayList< T > getResult();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Dw412, and welcome to StackOverflow.  If the answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You just carry the generic parameter over to the implementing class:

```
interface Obj<T extends Number> {
   ArrayList<T> getResult();
}

class Value<T extends Number> implements Obj<T> {
   ArrayList<T> getResult() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: Thank u for your favor!